# error in validation of project in eclipse - clean

Tags: eclipse, macos, maven-3

Since I updated my osx version this morning (no other changes) I get cleaning my project in eclipse:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Validation' on project 'XXXXX'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and the same result trying to run maven=> update project.

my configuration:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T18:37:52+01:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.1
Java version: 1.6.0_65, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: nl_NL, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

All suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Errors occurred during the build.
>   Errors running builder 'Validation' on project 'XXXXX'.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

A very general error that can arise due to a number of issues in settings and configurations. The most easy way out is to delete the project from eclipse, remove the directory `.metadata` from your workspace folder and then re-import the project ( or projects ).

Also try to check that the classpath of the eclipse is configured properly and no class-path variable has gotten disturbed during OS upgrade. Best way to check this is to goto the `Configure classpath` options of your project and make sure there isn't any issue there

Comment: Reloaded the project out of git after completely erasing the local instance. Gave the same result unfortunately.

Comment: You didnt have to do that. I just said to delete it from within eclipse ( not to delete files from system ) and then re-import it in a fresh workspace. Did you re-create the workspace as well?

Comment: Removing the .metadata and the project .setup file, and importing all projects again did solve the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Just removing folder **[workspace].metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.validation**  and restarting eclipse solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

following steps worked for me :
 1. Remove project from your eclipse, close eclipse.
 2. Import your project.
 3. Goto Project Properties and search for validation  and change accordingly as shown in  following figure. 
[image: Errors occurred during the build/clean]

Answer (score 0):

go to workspace/.metadata/.plugins/ 
delete all folders besides org.eclipse.core.runtime - this is your eclipse preferences / colors / perspectives..

warning this will remove all your projects from workspace only in eclipse, not the projects source files itself.

Then reimport your projects.

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete the whole project. Just do this:

Go to the org.eclipse.wst.validation directory and rename or delete the dep.index file, and restart eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the .metadata and then inside the folder go to org.eclipse.wst.validation directory of the workspace and delete the dep.index file, and restart eclipse.